# Vagrant synced folders and symlinks

Tags: vagrant

I am creating a dev environment using Vagrant. Assuming a directory structure as follows:

```
vagrant-dev
    Vagrantfile
    ...
    projects
        some-project -> ~/workspace/some-project
```

I want to share the projects folder with the VM. My intention is that our developers can simply symlink any project into the projects folder and this in turn be synced with the VM. However, on the VM it appears to not follow the symlink so you end up with a dead symlink pointing to the path on the host filesystem.

I'm not even sure if it's possible. Any thoughts anybody?

Comment: How should a vm follow symlinks on the host machine? I

Comment: Use docker, it's designed specifically with this sort of thing in mind